# SharePoint Framework: how to change TypeScript version used by gulp?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, typescript

I set up a new project using the yeoman template for SharePoint Framework web parts. Everything is working fine, I can run `gulp serve` and work in the local workbench. Good.

Now I need to change the TypeScript version. When running gulp serve the console is showing:

```
[09:12:38] [typescript] TypeScript version: 2.1.6
```

Where does this version come from? How can I bump this to 2.2.x?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mystery is solved. The typescript version is pulled in by `tslint` and in turn by the internal gulp-related typescript.

The output of "TypeScript version: 2.1.6" happens when the `tslint` task starts a typescript compilation:

[image]

Looking at the "package.json" in "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules" I can see this typescript dependency:

```
"@microsoft/gulp-core-build-typescript": ">=2.2.5 <3.0.0",
```

Now looking in "package.json" of "gulp-core-build-typescript" I see this typescript dependency:

```
"typescript": "~2.1.4"
```

This means: the highest typescript version starting with "2.1" will be used.

Looking at the available typescript versions shows "2.1.6" as being the highest one available:

`npm view typescript versions --json`

[image]

So that's why the version is 2.1.6. And since it's part of a chain of packages working together I won't touch it.