# How do I change the TypeScript version used by gulp?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, nodejs

In SharePoint Online, how do I update my typescript version? I think I narrowed down my problem to typescript versioning. My helloworld web part works. The one thing that it has that many of my other web parts do not have is `[tsc] typescript version: 3.3.4000` when I run `gulp serve`:

[image]

My many web parts that don't work, ALL have `[tsc] typescript version: 3.2.4` and throw an error for no typescript rules.

Here is the `[tsc] typescript version: 3.2.4` error message:

[image]

I think If I can get a working way to change the version of typescript when `gulp serve` runs may have a solution.

This is not a repeat of [SharePoint Framework: how to change TypeScript version used by gulp?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209553/sharepoint-framework-how-to-change-typescript-version-used-by-gulp). While **very** helpful, I do not have a dependency for typescript, `@microsoft/gulp-core-build-typescript": ">=2.2.5 <3.0.0` or anything like it.

I have rush compiler, which sets the typescript of 3.2:
`"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2": "^0.5.12",`

This is a good resource for people looking to change their typescript version:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/define-the-typescript-version-you-want-to-use-in-sharepoint-framework/

Using SPFX 1.10.0, npm 6.13.4, node 10.16.0, gulp 3.9.1, CLI 2.2.0,

I ran `npm list -g --depth=0` and have errors too:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing specific version of typescript like `npm install typescript@3.3.4000`? Also try adding the typescript dependency(`"dependencies": { "typescript": "^3.3.4000" }`) in your `package.json` file and then run `npm install`.

Comment: @Ganesh I tired both and it still has version 3.2.4 on `gulp serve` ..? and @Karthik While he offers good insight, I do not have those dependencies in my package.json :-)